# Is there a keyboard shortcut to deselect a file in Nautilus?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys

Is there a keyboard shortcut to deselect a selected file in Nautilus?

I'm asking because I often use a key to open to context menu (right click menu) but it's different depending on if a file is selected or not. For example, I can't create a new directory while a file is selected.

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle selected item on active *Nautilus* window.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to change/move the focused item (file or folder).

As a sidenote, that process is somehow *cleaner* with a different *gtk theme* than the default one *(Ambiance)*, the *Numix* gtk themes for example uses a *great outline* to highlight focused items.

Hope it helps.